# How to parse this to a POJO model using GSON or any other serializer

Tags: java, arrays, json

Can anyone tell me an approach to parse this response to a Java POJO model using GSON? I am not sure how to create a POJO for this. I am new to Java. Hence any help would be appreciated.  I did try to http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/# and i could see the data but it is not giving back the POJO model.

```
{
"data": {
    "help_data": [{
            "Help with delivery": [{
                    "Qus": "Estimating lastmile time",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                },
                {
                    "Qus": "Task not close",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "General issues": [{
                    "Qus": "Estimating lastmile time",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                },
                {
                    "Qus": "Batching",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Legal Terms & Contitions": [{
                    "Qus": "Estimating lastmile time",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                },
                {
                    "Qus": "Batching",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "FAQs": [{
                    "Qus": "Estimating lastmile time",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                },
                {
                    "Qus": "Batching",
                    "Ans": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.
Be sure to select JSON as the source type.